# Spring cloud data flow S3 source to listen to a folder in S3 bucket

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a stream which needs to listen to a folder in S3 bucket.

I could create a stream listening to the root of the bucket using following properties and could trigger the process.

```
app.s3-in.s3.supplier.remote-dir=mybucket
app.s3-in.cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=XXXXXXXXXX
app.s3-in.cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
app.s3-in.cloud.aws.region.static=ZZZZZZZZ
app.s3-in.cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
```

But unable to listen to a folder in the bucket.
I tried with following options:

```
app.s3-in.s3.supplier.remote-dir=mybucket/myfolder
app.s3-in.s3.supplier.remote-dir=mybucket/myfolder/
app.s3-in.s3.supplier.remote-dir=/mybucket/myfolder
app.s3-in.s3.supplier.remote-dir=/mybucket/myfolder/
```

I tried setting app.s3-in.path-style-access=true as well.

Comment: All the samples and tests actually use `remoteDir` instead of `remote-dir`, I suggest you give that a try.

Comment: Hi @CorneilduPlessis, I have tried with remoteDir but no luck

Comment: Hi @CorneilduPlessis, I tried all 4 options with remoteDir and nothing has worked. I want to know whether this particular functionality is supported in S3 source or not

Comment: Hi @CorneilduPlessis, please suggest if there is any other way or work around to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.s3-in.s3.supplier.remote-dir=mybucket
app.s3-in.s3.supplier.filename-pattern=myfolder/**
```

(or some variation of the file pattern).

Comment: I tried with filename-pattern as well but result is not as expected

Comment: what was the result @VenuGopal? Same as w/ only specifying the `remote-dir`? Be sure that your pattern will match the value from s3 `file.getKey()`. Can you list one of the full file key here? Obfuscate any private info w/ `***`.

Comment: Hi @onobc, I tried with a simple stream to transfer files from one location to another location in S3.  I have following files in my bucket.
test1_input.xlsx,test2_input.xlsx,myinput/test3_input.xlsx,myinput/test4_input.xlsx and myoutput/
when I tried with app.s3-in.s3.supplier.filename-pattern=*.xlsx I see test1, test2 files moved to myoutput 
but when I tried with app.s3-in.s3.supplier.filename-pattern=myinput/*.xlsx ( and also tried with filename-pattern=myinput/**)
I see test1, test2 files in myout folder along with a 0 Bytes file named myinput, but not file3 and file4 as expected.

Comment: When I tried dropping a file named test5_input.xlsx in root after deploying these 2 streams, test5 moved to myout folder in both the cases. 
But when I tried dropping the same file under myinput, the file could not be moved to myout folder which is expected with second stream.

Comment: I see following error message in log of S3 input component:
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing 'mybucket' to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying 'mybucket/myinput/test3_input.xlsx' from the remote to the local directory; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/folders/jt/wclvj13x6fv564hdjzvvmx9w0000gn/T/s3-supplier/myinput/test3_input.xlsx.tmp (Not a directory)

Comment: @VenuGopal what are the settings for the S3 sink (`bucket`, `key-expression`)? 

I would focus only on the S3 source first and then once thats working get the S3 sink working. It would simplify things if you instead use `S3 source + Log sink` for the pipeline.

Comment: Following are S3 sink properties
app.s3-out-sink.cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=XXXXXXX
app.s3-out-sink.cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=XXXX
app.s3-out-sink.cloud.aws.region.static=XXXXX
app.s3-out-sink.cloud.aws.stack.auto=false
app.s3-out-sink.s3.consumer.bucket=mybucket
app.s3-out-sink.s3.consumer.key-expression='myoutput/‘+headers.file_name
I have tried with S3 source + log sink as well. 
I'll create a new one and post my findings here

Comment: I'm could see an object reference printed in log sink for each file

Comment: Hi @venu it turns out to be a bug in the S3 source app. Please follow https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/issues/431#issuecomment-1438963366 for fix and workaround. Once that ticket completes I will update this SO thread w/ a summary answer.

Comment: yes @onobc, I'm following this, it was created by me there. thanks for your time and guidance